Send email notification to admin when new user registers via online form (form builder)
I have created an online (public) form for user registration (add to mailing list) with form builder. I want the registration to be verified by an admin. And I want to notify the admin by email of each new registration.
I have checked "Verify submission before processing", which allows for manual verification. So far so good.
When I check this, a new checkbox is desplayed: "Allow verification by email". Is this referring to the function I need? It says: "The data can be processed via email verification. Email field should be included in the form for this functionality."
Which email does this refer to? (The user's email has been added to the form, and it seems the user get's a confirmation email anyway, so it seems to me it must be the
Email of an admin who can verify the application. But where should I add this email address?)
When I check the checkbox, it shows a dropdown "Email template". Is there a special template to notify an admin?
Thanks for your advice
Martin

